# $X \in Mat_{n,n}(\mathbb F)$. Prove $XA = AX \ \forall A \in Mat_{n,n}(\mathbb F) \iff X = sI, s \in \mathbb F$

Tags: linear-algebra

$X \in Mat_{n,n}(\mathbb F)$. Prove $XA = AX \ \forall A \in Mat_{n,n}(\mathbb F) \iff X = sI, s \in \mathbb F$

Proving that $X = sI \Rightarrow XA = AX$ is easy by manipulation the multiplication and using the identity $IA = AI$.

However how do I prove $XA = AX \Rightarrow X = sI$ ?

Also if $A \in Mat_{n,n}(\mathbb R)$ is invertible and the sum of every row is 1. How does one prove that $A^{-1}$ has the same property ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $E_{ij}$ be a matrix with $1$ on the $ij$ place and zero elsewhere. What is $XE_{ij}$? What is $E_{ij}X$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=(x_{ij})$ hence we have 
$$X=\sum_{1\le i,j\le n}x_{ij}E_{ij}$$
where $(E_{ij})$ is the standard basis of $M_n(\Bbb F)$ and recall that
$$E_{ij}E_{kl}=\delta_{jk}E_{il}$$
where $\delta_{jk}$ is the Kronecker symbol.
 Now by taking $A=E_{kl} $ we have
\begin{align}AX=XA&\iff E_{kl}\sum_{1\le i,j\le n}x_{ij}E_{ij}=\left(\sum_{1\le i,j\le n}x_{ij}E_{ij}\right)E_{kl}\\
&\iff\sum_{1\le j\le n}x_{lj}E_{kj}=\sum_{1\le i\le n}x_{ik}E_{il}\\
&\iff \left(x_{ll}=x_{kk}=s\;\forall k,l\right)\land(x_{lk}=0\;\forall k\ne l)\\
&\iff X=sI_n\end{align}